# Conditional property in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

How can I add an additional property based on a condition?

With my code below I get the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'some View' (result of 'Self.overlay(_:alignment:)') to type 'some View' (result of 'Self.onTapGesture(count:perform:)')

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ConditionalProperty: View {
    @State var overlay: Bool
    var body: some View {
        var view = Image(systemName: "photo")
            .resizable()
            .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: self.tap)
        if self.overlay {
            view = view.overlay(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red))
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func tap() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

Thanks to [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/conditionally-apply-modifier-in-swiftui/32815) I found an option with a very simple interface:

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .if(shouldBeRed) { $0.foregroundColor(.red) }
```

Enabled by this extension:

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<Transform: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Transform) -> some View {
        if condition { transform(self) }
        else { self }
    }
}
```

Here is a great blog post with additional tips for conditional modifiers: https://fivestars.blog/swiftui/conditional-modifiers.html

**Warning:** Conditional view modifiers come with some caveats, and you may want to reconsider using the code above after reading this: https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/

Personally I would choose to use this approach in answer to OP in order to avoid the potential issues mentioned in that article:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: self.tap)
        .overlay(self.overlay ? Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red) : nil)
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Did some thing change? It says Cannot find type 'View' in scope

Comment: @chitgoks you're missing `import SwiftUI`

Answer (score 14):

In SwiftUI terminology, you're not adding a property. You're adding a modifier.

The problem here is that, in SwiftUI, every modifier returns a type that depends on what it's modifying.

```
var view = Image(systemName: "photo")
    .resizable()
    .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: self.tap)

// view has some deduced type like GestureModifier<SizeModifier<Image>>

if self.overlay {
    let newView = view.overlay(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red))
    // newView has a different type than view, something like
    // OverlayModifier<GestureModifier<SizeModifier<Image>>>
}
```

Since `newView` has a different type than `view`, you can't just assign `view = newView`.

One way to solve this is to always use the `overlay` modifier, but to make the overlay transparent when you don't want it visible:

```
var body: some View {
    return Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: self.tap)
        .overlay(Circle().foregroundColor(overlay ? .red : .clear))
}
```

Another way to handle it is to use the type eraser `AnyView`:

```
var body: some View {
    let view = Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: self.tap)
    if overlay {
        return AnyView(view.overlay(Circle().foregroundColor(.red)))
    } else {
        return AnyView(view)
    }
}
```

The recommendations I have seen from Apple engineers are to avoid using `AnyView` because is less efficient than using fully typed views. For example, [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/1136069258964680706) and [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/1144043290540429313).

Comment: The actual performance testing of `AnyView` does not reveal any negative implications when using it: https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-performance-battle-anyview-vs-group-55bf852158df

Answer (score 14):

[Rob Mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) already [explained pretty well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467548/14351818) why this behavior appears and proposes two solutions (Transparant overlays or using `AnyView`). A third more elegant way is to use  [_ConditionalContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildeither(second:)).

A simple way to create `_ConditionalContent` is by writing `if` `else` statements inside a group or stack. Here is an example using a group:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConditionalProperty: View {
    @State var overlay: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if overlay {
                base.overlay(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red))
            } else {
                base
            }
        }
    }
    
    var base: some View {
        Image("photo")
            .resizable()
            .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: self.tap)
    }

    func tap() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that by default, SwiftUI treats the static type of a view as its identifier for animations ([explained by Joe Groff here](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-swiftuis-view-a-pat/28029/13?u=mayoff)). In your solution, the two subviews (with/without overlay) are therefore treated as unrelated views. If one applies an animation, it may apply differently in your solution than in mine. That's not necessarily wrong, just something to be aware of. It can be worked around using the `.id` modifier.

Answer (score 5):

## Use conditional modifiers including `if - else` expressions only if you have absolutely no choice.

The huge disadvantage of conditional modifiers is they create new views which can cause unexpected behavior for example they will break animations.

Almost all modifiers accept a `nil` value for *no change* so if possible use **always** something like

```
@State var overlay: Bool

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .overlay(overlay ? Circle().foregroundColor(Color.red) : nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer similar to what Kiran Jasvanee posted, but simplified:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .modifier(ConditionalModifier(isBold: true))
    }
}

struct ConditionalModifier: ViewModifier {

    var isBold: Bool

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if self.isBold {
                content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14))
            }
            else{
                content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is that there's no need to add this extension:

```
extension View {
    func conditionalView(_ value: Bool) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ConditionalModifier(isBold: value))
  }
}
```

In the `ConditionalModifier` struct, you could also eliminate the Group view and instead use the `@ViewBuilder` decorator, like so:

```
struct ConditionalModifier: ViewModifier {

    var isBold: Bool

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        // Group {
            if self.isBold {
                content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14))
            }
            else{
                content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 14))
            }
        // }
    }
}
```

You must either use a Group view (or some other parent view) or the `@ViewBuilder` decorator if you want to conditionally display views.

Here's another example in which the the text of a button can be toggled between bold and not bold:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var makeBold = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.makeBold.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Tap me to Toggle Bold")
                .modifier(ConditionalModifier(isBold: makeBold))
        })

    }
}

struct ConditionalModifier: ViewModifier {

    var isBold: Bool

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if self.isBold {
                content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14))
            }
            else{
                content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Conditional modifier on a view breaks the ability of SwiftUI to identify the view when it changes state during a redraw. This results in unexpected behavior including strange animation transitions, so please avoid doing it. Use ternaries instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Preferred way to implement `Conditional Properties` is below. It works well if you have Animations applied.
*I tried a few other ways, but it affects the animation I've applied.*

You can add your condition in place of false I've kept  **.conditionalView(`false`)**.

Below, You can switch to `true` to check the **'Hello, World!'** will be shown **BOLD**.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        .conditionalView(false)
        // or use:
        // .modifier(ConditionalModifier(isBold: false))

    }
}

extension View {
    func conditionalView(_ value: Bool) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ConditionalModifier(isBold: value))
  }
}

struct ConditionalModifier: ViewModifier {
    var isBold: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    Group {
        if self.isBold {
            content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14))
        }else{
            content.font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 14))
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `conditionalView` extension for `View`. Initialize the `ConditionalModifier` struct directly using `.modifier(ConditionalModifier(isBold : viewIsBold))`

Comment: @PeterSchorn I think I got your point, would suggest you add your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as this

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
  let value: Double
  let maxValue: Double
  
  private let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
  
  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .strokeBorder(Color.yellow, lineWidth: lineWidth)
      .overlay(optionalOverlay)
  }
  
  private var progressEnd: CGFloat {
    CGFloat(value) / CGFloat(maxValue)
  }
  
  private var showProgress: Bool {
    value != maxValue
  }
  
  @ViewBuilder private var optionalOverlay: some View {
    if showProgress {
      Circle()
        .inset(by: lineWidth / 2)
        .trim(from: 0, to: progressEnd)
        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: lineWidth)
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
    }
  }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      SomeView(value: 40, maxValue: 100)
      
      SomeView(value: 100, maxValue: 100)
    }
      .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 100, height: 100))
  }
}
```