# Add a conditional modifier

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I'm attempting to create a text view where some of the modifiers are based on a condition (In my case whether the user is running IOS16 +)

**Here's my attempt:**

```
// extension suggested by: Dalija Prasnikar
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<Transform: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Transform) -> some View {
        if condition { transform(self) }
        else { self }
    }
}

// the function used to verify the version
    private var isiOS16AndAbove: Bool {
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

}

```
    // the text widget
    Text(text)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.6)
        .foregroundColor(myColorFont)
         // this fails
        .if(isiOS16AndAbove) { view in
            view.background(Color.red)
         // also this
         .if(isiOS16AndAbove) { $0.contentTransition(.numericText()) }
    }
```

The error I receive:

> Value of type 'some View' has no member 'if'

How can I chain conditional modifiers instead of writing the same code twice (once for each case)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional property in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467353/conditional-property-in-swiftui)

Comment: You need an extension on View that will define `if`

Comment: I can't get this to work.. It still tells me that a certain modifier I'm trying to add is only available at IOS16+ I edited the code.

Comment: Your isiOS16AndAbove function is incorrect. Also you don't need guard there just return result of #available((iOS 16, *)

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar You are correct, I fixed it. However, the error persists.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what is the current issue including error message. If you no longer have issue with `if` member then remove that from the question. Currently it is not clear what your exact issue is.

Comment: I ran your code and there is no error, you probably just forgot to close closure somewhere, check your { } signs

Comment: This approach is not going to work for any modifier that is not compatible with iOS below 16, and so it's pointless. The incompatible code must be directly under `#available` (or `@available`) check. So reconsider your approach to either pass a protocol (which can then be implemented with iOS16 compatible / legacy way, or even make your version specific modifiers explicit - easier to manage, and not temptation to use too many of them