# How to have a conditional modifier based on the os version in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to programming and I joined StackOverflow today. I hope I can ask based on the guidelines:

I'm starting SwiftUI and it seems it has many code that works only for iOS 17, take a look at this:

```
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    Text("Hello World")
        .font(.title.bold())
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

        // This modifier only works on iOS 17
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
} else {
    Text("Hello World")
        .font(.title.bold())
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

        .foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

One of the first things I learned is to not repeat the same code but how can I apply different modifiers easily without repeating the code? something like this:

```
Text("Hello World")
    .font(.title.bold())
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

  if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    .foregroundStyle(.red)
  } else {
    .foregroundColor(.red)
  }
```

P.S: I have seen [posts like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467353/conditional-property-in-swiftui) to implement a custom modifier that takes a bool as input, but it can't take the os version in a way that the compiler understands like `#available(iOS 17.0, *)`.

##### Update

I know we can achieve something similar for the os check like the following, but I'm looking for the check for the version in the same general way:

```
Text("Hello World")
    .font(.title.bold())
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

  #if os(iOS)
    .foregroundStyle(.red)
  #else
    .foregroundColor(.red)
```

Thanks for considering my question

Comment: Please help me improve my question if needed to have my answer. Thanks in advanced 

Comment: .foregroundStyle(.red) is available from iOS 15.0, What was your min target OS version?

Comment: My main target is iOS 13, but Im asking generally. I know it is possible to do for the os directly like `#if os(macOS)` but it seems not natively possible for os **version**

Comment: if that is the case. I too would suggest @burnsi's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve something quite *similar* with a simple extension:

```
extension View {
    func apply<V: View>(@ViewBuilder _ block: (Self) -> V) -> V { block(self) }
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
Text("Hello World")
    .font(.title.bold())
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .apply {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            $0.foregroundStyle(.red)
        } else {
            $0.foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
```

Note that you can `apply` any modifier on any view you like and it is pretty general as you asked.

Comment: Nice use of closure! Thanks a lot! I think I take this as the answer since it is the nearest to the native syntax I'm looking for. 

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler approach to this.

Still using a view modifier. But the modifier is specially for foreground styling. So you can check your condition inside of it.

e.g.

```
struct ForegroundModifier: ViewModifier{
    
    let color: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *){
            content.foregroundStyle(color)
        }else{
            content.foregroundColor(color)
        }
    }
}

extension View{
    func myForegroundStyle(_ color: Color) -> some View{
        modifier(ForegroundModifier(color: color))
    }
}
```

and apply it like:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TestThis")
            .myForegroundStyle(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this good solution. But this forces me to have like extra 15 lines of code for each modifier to make it backward compatible. I need a more general way to do for all modifiers and other code. +1 for your effort. Thanks

Comment: For example `cornerRadius` also asks to use `clipShape` instead, or `onChange` asks me to use the one `with a two or zero parameter action closure instead.` in newer iOS versions like 17. Is this a good practice to have a custom `ViewModifier` for each of these?

Comment: I don´t think there is an easier approach to this. Backwards compatibilty isn´t Apples strong suit.